# Checking for selected Combobox item - WinApi C++

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

Alright so I had a question about checking for the ComboBox item, I currently have used "ComboBox_AddString" to add the items and I was using ComboBox_GetText passing that off to a wchar_t, then checking if that wchar_t equals to L"Minecraft" EVERYTHING in the debugger matches for variable names but it skips over it like it's not equivalent. Is there a "mainstream" way of checking for selected ComboBox Items.

```
            wchar_t* szProccessToKill = new wchar_t[20];
            GetWindowText(hUserBox, szProccessToKill, 20);
            wchar_t* szGameSelect = new wchar_t[20];
            ComboBox_GetText(comboBox, szGameSelect, 20);

            if (szGameSelect == L"Minecraft")
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, L"HAI", L"NULL", NULL);
            }
```

This is the whole code if you want to take a look at it and let me know if there was a better way, I need this to work because it is a GameLauncher and I decided to have a ComboBox instead of millions of buttons. I seen people use SendMessage but I didn't know why since ComboBox_AddString worked perfectly.

```
case WM_CREATE:
     {
        CreateWindowEx(NULL, BUTTON, L"Check for process", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX , 5, 35, 150, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);
        comboBox = CreateWindow(L"combobox", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST , 250, 5, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        ComboBox_AddString(comboBox, L"Minecraft");
        ComboBox_AddString(comboBox, L"Smite");
        CreateWindow(BUTTON, L"Launch", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 250, 30, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)4, NULL, NULL);
        hUserBox = CreateWindow(L"static", L"Awaiting Commands...", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 240, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;
     }

    case WM_COMMAND:

        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {
            case 4:
            {
                wchar_t* szProccessToKill = new wchar_t[20];
                GetWindowText(hUserBox, szProccessToKill, 20);
                wchar_t* szGameSelect = new wchar_t[20];
                ComboBox_GetText(comboBox, szGameSelect, 20);

                if (szGameSelect == L"Minecraft")
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"HAI", L"NULL", NULL);
                }
```

Comment: I think `Combobox_AddString` is just a macro that calls `SendMessage`.

Comment: I think you can probably fit 20 character strings on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (szGameSelect == L"Minecraft")
```

This isn't a string comparison!  It's comparing two pointers, which of course won't be equal. Instead you need [`wcscmp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx):

```
if (wcscmp(szGameSelect, L"Minecraft") == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, I just remember something about array of characters is primarily a memory address (Kinda like a pointer) so I get confused sometimes and compare them.

Comment: @KingRaider: Your question is tagged C++, so you should be using C++ strings (`std::string` or `std::wstring`) instead of character arrays.  You can compare string values using the `==` operator. On the other hand, if you know the *index* of the `Minecraft` item in the combobox (which `ComboBox_AddString()` gives you), then you don't need to use `ComboBox_GetText()`, just use [`ComboBox_GetCurSel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856471.aspx) instead and compare the return value to that index.

Comment: @RemyLebeau unfortunately the Windows API wasn't designed with C++ in mind, and if you're not using a framework then old-fashioned strings are just easier to deal with. +1 for mentioning `GetCurSel`.